# Can't adjust brightness on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, display, brightness, display-driver

After updating my windows in the ***system update (settings)***, and updating my drivers using ***driverBooster*** and ***Lenovo system Updater tool***, I can't control my brightness anymore.
I tried all the solutions availaible on google, like:

I already have the latest Display Adapter Drivers.

I have deleted the hidden devices under PnP Monitors.

I have reanbled my PnP Monitor.

I ran a troublshooter but it didn't detect any problems.

Comment: Using the manufacturer's tool should be fine but DriverBooster is mostly a SCAM like any similar tools.

Comment: I agree. I have Lenovo machines. Forget Driver Booster. Why change plug and pay to solve this. Maybe just try a Windows 10 Repair install to see if that fixes the issue - 50:50 in this case.

Comment: Undo everything you did with DriverBooster - this might fix the problem.

Comment: @harrymc unfortunately i have disabled the restore point feature before doing the update

Comment: You have also done too many other actions that contribute nothing except trouble. I suggest doing [Repair Install](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html). If this doesn't help, you're fast approaching a total re-installation.